# CGContextDrawImage in Retina draws image pixelated?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, iphone-4

I need to draw images into a CALayer because I need to perform various effects, animations and filters on it. When I do simple drawing into the CGContext no matter what I do it always gets drawn pixelated... 
What's the right way to draw onto a context in retina?

This is what I'm doing now:

```
CGImageRef plateImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"] CGImage];
CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(plateImage), height = CGImageGetHeight(plateImage);
CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

NSLog(@"Scale: %f\nWidth: %f\nHeight: %f", scale, width, height);
CGContextTranslateCTM(_context, 0, height / scale);
CGContextScaleCTM(_context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextDrawImage(_context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width / scale, height / scale), plateImage);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to set the contents scale of the layer appropriately.

```
myLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale
```

Comment: Aaaaaa! I was looking everywhere in CG docs - didn't think for a minute it was a layer issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem but the solution didn't seem to work.

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` turned out to be causing my problem. I'm posting my solution here for future users with the same problem.

From iOS 4.0 you should use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
```

instead of

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
```

If you don't want pixelated images.

Comment: Thank you! I can't say I understand why this works, but it does.

Comment: Worth noting that I had the best results combining this with the accepted answer:
`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);`

Answer (score 0):

Updated @Tieme's solution for Swift 4

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
```

instead of

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
```